# GDB shows broken instruction address offset

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, gdb

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
```

I'm debugging with gdb and faced some weird address offset. I have a shared library written in `C++` with a function `foo` which disassembles as follows (the first fragment):

```
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x00007ffff5c82d70 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x00007ffff5c82d71 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00007ffff5c82d74 <+4>:     push   r15
   0x00007ffff5c82d76 <+6>:     push   r14
   0x00007ffff5c82d78 <+8>:     push   r13
   0x00007ffff5c82d7a <+10>:    push   r12
   0x00007ffff5c82d7c <+12>:    push   rbx
   0x00007ffff5c82d7d <+13>:    sub    rsp,0x18
   0x00007ffff5c82d81 <+17>:    test   rdi,rdi
   0x00007ffff5c82d84 <+20>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x34],r8d
   0x00007ffff5c82d88 <+24>:    je     0x7ffff5c82e58 <foo+232>
   0x00007ffff5c82d8e <+30>:    mov    r15,rsi
   0x00007ffff5c82d91 <+33>:    mov    r14,rdx
   0x00007ffff5c82d94 <+36>:    mov    r13d,ecx
   0x00007ffff5c82d97 <+39>:    mov    rbx,rdi
   0x00007ffff5c82d9a <+42>:    jmp    0x7ffff5c82ded <foo+125>
   0x00007ffff5c82d9c <+44>:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
   # Where do these negative offsets come from?
   0x00007ffff5c82da0 <+-1632>: mov    r9d,DWORD PTR [r12]
   0x00007ffff5c82da4 <+-1628>: lea    rcx,[rip+0xcadbe2]        
   0x00007ffff5c82dab <+-1621>: lea    rdx,[rip+0xcadde6]        
   0x00007ffff5c82db2 <+-1614>: lea    rdi,[rip+0xcadb67]   
   #...
   # negative offset of some unrelated function `bar`
   0x00007ffff5c82e19 <+-1511>: js     0x7ffff5c82dde <bar+4294965726>
```

Such negative offsets point are interpreted as belonging to some unrelated function (I did not find anything that could match these function up) `bar`.

Such things causes confusion when using GUI gdb frontend.

**Any idea why gdb may show such negative instruction offset? Is it a GDB bug? If so, is there any workaround?**

I tried to find out what is the `objdump` output regarding this function and did not notice anything strange (the same fragment as in the gdb example):

```
$ objdump -M intel -d libsomelib.so | grep -A 100 -i "0000000000e78d70"                                                        
0000000000e78d70 <foo>:                                                                                   
  e78d70:       55                      push   rbp                                                                                                                                                                 
  e78d71:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp                                                                                                                                                             
  e78d74:       41 57                   push   r15                                                                                                                                                                 
  e78d76:       41 56                   push   r14                                                                                                                                                                 
  e78d78:       41 55                   push   r13                                                                                                                                                                 
  e78d7a:       41 54                   push   r12                                                                                                                                                                 
  e78d7c:       53                      push   rbx                                                                                                                                                                 
  e78d7d:       48 83 ec 18             sub    rsp,0x18                                                                                                                                                            
  e78d81:       48 85 ff                test   rdi,rdi                                                                                                                                                             
  e78d84:       44 89 45 cc             mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x34],r8d                                                                                                                                            
  e78d88:       0f 84 ca 00 00 00       je     e78e58 <foo+0xe8>                                          
  e78d8e:       49 89 f7                mov    r15,rsi                                                                                                                                                             
  e78d91:       49 89 d6                mov    r14,rdx                                                                                                                                                             
  e78d94:       41 89 cd                mov    r13d,ecx                                                                                                                                                            
  e78d97:       48 89 fb                mov    rbx,rdi                                                                                                                                                             
  e78d9a:       eb 51                   jmp    e78ded <foo+0x7d>                                          
  e78d9c:       0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]                                                                                                                                                 
  e78da0:       45 8b 0c 24             mov    r9d,DWORD PTR [r12]                                                                                                                                                 
  e78da4:       48 8d 0d e2 db ca 00    lea    rcx,[rip+0xcadbe2]                                                           
  e78dab:       48 8d 15 e6 dd ca 00    lea    rdx,[rip+0xcadde6]                                                           
  e78db2:       48 8d 3d 67 db ca 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xcadb67]                                                        
  //...
  //just fine
  e78e19:       78 c3                   js     e78dde <foo+0x6e>
```

The clear difference between the output of the gdb and objdump can be seen in the final line.

GDB:

```
0x00007ffff5c82e19 <+-1511>: js     0x7ffff5c82dde <bar+4294965726>
```

objdump:

```
e78e19:       78 c3                   js     e78dde <foo+0x6e>
```

Comment: Appears to be data interpreted as code - control cannot reach those instruction, at least not from what is shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why gdb may show such negative instruction offset?

Yes: in `<bar+4294965726>`, GDB interprets offset as signed int: `4294965726 == -1570`

> Is it a GDB bug?

Yes.

Unfortunately it's not clear how to reproduce this, or why GDB decided to show offset from `bar` instead of showing offset from `foo`. And without that, a proper bug report would be hard to create.

Comment: What's interesting is that in the disassembly gdb correctly shows `je     0x7ffff5c82e58 <foo+232>` and later on at that address it would have presumably showed a negative offset from `bar` instead. Sounds like it has two different ways to resolve symbols so it isn't even consistent.